# very large schematics in altium designer

Tags: pcb-design, design, schematics, altium

I want to design a pcb of a large circuit schematic diagram, How I can manage very large schematics in altium designer?

Comment: How large?  Altium understands hierarchical designs so you can place blocks on one sheet and have the details of that block on another, each of these sheets can also have blocks to give a nested design.  Alternatively you can have a flat design and use global signals to  go from page to page.

Comment: As multiple sheets. If you're asking about specific details of handling multi-sheet schematics, ask a more detailed question.

Comment: ...And in the case where the OP means a physically large sheet (a strange and unusual situation), then one can define a large schematic sheet template.  I have done prints as large as 1 meter by 1.5 meters.  Options-> Document Options-> Sheet Options-> Custom Style.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: thank you all. how can I manage blocks, data buses, links ... can you suggest me a toturial?

Comment: Look up *altium hierarchical design tutorial* on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use the hierarchical structure, as others have suggested. Effectively you draw multiple schematics (each counted as one sheet) and then you have one top-level sheet that connects them all together. You can find Altium documentation for hierarchical designs [here](http://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/((Multi-Sheet+and+Multi-Channel+Design))_AD).

You can also make what are referred to as *flat* designs, in which case you still draw multiple sheets but you do not need a "top-level" document. Instead you simply use sheet-to-sheet connectors and they link all the sheets together.

The type of design is selected by going to the `Project` menu, selecting `Project Options`, clicking the `Options` tab, and changing the dropdown menu in the `Net Identifier Scope` panel to whichever style you prefer:

[image]

Comment: I have configured my schematic to A4 paper. The components seem extremely large. Is this normal?

Comment: @A.Vieira A4 paper is quite small, so I would expect the components to appear larger than usual, especially if they were drawn on a sheet much larger (A2, for example). The components themselves are the same size regardless of the sheet size but when placed on a small sheet they just look larger.

Comment: Yes, but the main IC is 7.5cm tall on the page. One schematic block occupies a lot. Maybe I'll just do A3 or A2 and then print to A4.